# Cant publish my Blazor WASM application, error 500.30

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I'm having problems publishing my Blazor WASM (core 3.1) project to a shared host.

I have a Blazor server project (core 3.1) that runs fine on the production server (shared hosting).

When I create a Blazor Wasm project and try to publish that, I get the "HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure" error, but only when I created a project that is core hosted.

I first thought it had something to do with the authentication so I added

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    },
```

in appsettings.json but that didint work, so I thought that it might have something to do with CORS, so I added

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: "_myAllowSpecificOrigins",
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("https://XX",
                                                      "http://XX");
                              });
        });
```

in

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
and

```
app.UseCors("_myAllowSpecificOrigins");
```

in
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

But I cant even get a proper error message. Im new to all this so Im not really sure what Im doing, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you build the project? If yes, how do you publish it? To what location, hoster etc?

Comment: Hi @DanielW., build works great, I can run it locally, I publish to a local folder and then upload.

Comment: Does it fail after upload or during publish to local folder?

Comment: Hi @DanielW. it fails when running it on the shared host.

Comment: I think this may be an error in the web hosting. Otherwise the error message not fits to web assembly. Can you test a different host?

Comment: Hi @DanielW., sorry, only have access to one host. And they don't have any support :(

Comment: What about try a 30 day free azure test account with azure storage?